# graphobject goes out of ZedGraph Axis frame

Tags: c#, .net, zedgraph

I am working on a custom radio frequency analyzer where I have to plot the radio packets as rectangles using ZedGraph. The work is almost done and the graph is working fine but the issues I am facing are: (1) rectangles go out of Axis frame (2) the mouse cursor shows total 3 values but I need to show only (x,y) values. Here is the Code:

```
    private void CreateGraph(ZedGraphControl zgc)
    {

        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;            
        myPane.Title.IsVisible = false;
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time(Mili-Seconds)";                   

        if (isStartPoint)
        {                
            startPoint = PacketHandler.getFirstPoint();               
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = startPoint;

            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep=100;
            myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep=100;

            myPane.YAxis.IsVisible = false;
            myPane.YAxis.Title.IsVisible = false; 
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinAuto=true;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = true;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep=10;
            myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinorStep=10;
            isStartPoint = false;
        }

        double x = PacketHandler.getMcTime();
        double y = 5;
        double w = PacketHandler.getPacketWidth();
        double h = 5;
        int pColor = PacketHandler.getRowColor();
        BoxObj box; 
        if (pColor == 0)
        {
            box = new BoxObj(x, y, w, h, Color.Black, Color.Tomato);
        }
        else if (pColor == 1)
        {
            box = new BoxObj(x, y, w, h, Color.Black, Color.Beige);
        }
        else if (pColor == 2)
        {
            box = new BoxObj(x, y, w, h, Color.Black, Color.LightSeaGreen);
        }
        else if (pColor == 3)
        {
            box = new BoxObj(x, y, w, h, Color.Black, Color.GreenYellow);
        }
        else
        {
            box = new BoxObj(x, y, w, h, Color.Black, Color.Tomato);
        }

        box.IsVisible = true;
        box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
        box.ZOrder = ZOrder.A_InFront;
        //zgc.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Add(box);
        myPane.GraphObjList.Add(box);           

        zgc.AxisChange();
        zgc.Invalidate();

    }
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

set `IsClippedToChartRect` property of the `BoxObject` to true, it will make the rectangle to be plotted within the Axis rectangle.